# How to shake up and down using Accelerometer in Android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I tried the following way, but it doesn't work perfectly.. If device is kept in normal way, then also it fires shake event.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // only allow one update every 200Ms.
    if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 200) {

        lastUpdate = curTime;

        x = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_X];
        y = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Y];
        z = event.values[SensorManager.DATA_Z];

        Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        if (Round(y, 4) > 22) {
            vibrate.vibrate(200);
            Log.d("sensor", "==== Up Detected===");

        } else if (Round(y, 4) < -20) {
            vibrate.vibrate(200);
            Log.d("sensor", "==== Down Detected=== ");

        }

        mLastX = x;
        mLastY = y;
        mLastZ = z;
    }

}

public static float Round(float Rval, int Rpl) {
    float p = (float) Math.pow(10, Rpl);

    Rval = Rval * p;
    float tmp = Math.round(Rval);
    return (float) tmp / p;
}
```

Please Help.

Any Help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sensor values are very raw and noisy.  You need to add a layer of digital signal processing on top of them to get good results.  Just using the raw values will lead to a lot of jitter in your results.  You're trying to do some basic ones with your time delay, but you need to do more filtering.

Also, you're vibrating in response to a shake.  That vibrate will cause the accelerometer to see movement, leading to more false positives.

Comment: I didn't got the first part of your answer

Comment: The values you get from the sensors can't be trusted as is-  they have a lot of false readings and aren't really exact.  There's a study in electrical engineering on how to analyze and adjust signal readings, it's called Digital Signals Processing.  One o the concepts in there is a filter-  its a way of accepting, rejecting, or partially accepting a reading.  You need one, I just have no idea the proper one to use.

Answer (score 0):

Apply lowpass filter on as your y-axis values.

The basic filter will be as mentioned in documentation.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
  // In this example, alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT),
 // where t is the low-pass filter's time-constant and
 // dT is the event delivery rate.

 final float alpha = 0.8;

 // Isolate the force of gravity with the low-pass filter.
 gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
 gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
 gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

 // Remove the gravity contribution with the high-pass filter.
 linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
 linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
 linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
  }
```